# Can we use match to check the type of a class

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, match

I'm new to scala, and I'm learning the `match` keyword now.

I wanna know if we can use the keyword `match` to check the type of a class. My code is:

```
object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val x = "AA"
        checkType(x)
    }

    def checkType(cls: AnyRef) {
        cls match {
            case String => println("is a String")
            case Date => println("is a Date")
            case _ => println("others")
        }
    }
}
```

The code can't be compiled, so, it's impossible to do this? What is the scala-way to check the type of a class? Is it:

```
if(cls.isInstanceOf[String]) { ... }
else if(cls.isInstanceOf[Date]) { ... }
else { ... }
```

Right?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

This however *will* compile:

```
def checkType(cls: AnyRef) {                    
  cls match {                                 
    case s: String => println("is a String")
    case d: Date => println("is a Date")    
    case _ => println("others")             
  }                                                   
}
```

... or the simplified version of that:

```
def checkType(cls: AnyRef) =
  cls match {                                 
    case _: String => println("is a String")
    case _: Date => println("is a Date")    
    case _ => println("others")             
  }
```

Comment: or, **even** simpler: since match yields a value, is to put the `println(...)` around it and have the cases resolve to the appropriate strings.

Answer (score 15):

You need a identifier before the type annotation in `case` statement.

Try this and it should work:

```
object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val x = "AA"
        checkType(x)
    }

    def checkType(cls: AnyRef) {
        cls match {
            case x: String => println("is a String:"+ x)
            case x: Date => println("is a Date:" + x)
            case _ => println("others")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, as it's impossible to do anything with the checked value inside the case clauses (in this snippet 'cls') unless it is given a name other than the special _. In many cases you'd want to take action on the object based on its type and this answer is well geared towards that use case. For as much as it matters...